# Could someone help me adding a return value to each coding path of my method?

Tags: c#, methods, return

I'm an immediate beginner in coding and I get the error message, that my code would not return a value in each path. 
Could someone help me solve this problem?
The methods and classes, you see are from the Rhino Geometry library.
Thank you, for reading my post.
Best wishes, 
Oliver

bool ComputePaths(ref Curve sprout, List segments, List nodes)
  {

```
double threshold = 0.5;
bool success = false;

while(success = false)
{
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
  {
    Vector3d a = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtStart;
    Vector3d b = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtEnd;
    if (a.Length < threshold | b.Length < threshold)
    {
      Point3d origin = new Point3d();
      origin = sprout.PointAtStart;

      List<Curve> segmentsToJoin = new List<Curve>();
      segmentsToJoin.Add(sprout);
      segmentsToJoin.Add(segments[i]);
      Curve[] segmentsJoined = new Curve[1];
      segmentsJoined = Curve.JoinCurves(segmentsToJoin, threshold);
      sprout = segmentsJoined[0];

      Vector3d c = sprout.PointAtStart - origin;
      if (c.Length > threshold)
      {
        sprout.Reverse();
      }

      for (int j = 0; j < nodes.Count; j++)
      {
        Vector3d d = sprout.PointAtEnd - nodes[j];
        if (d.Length < threshold)
        {
          success = true;
          return success;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      counter += 1;
      if(counter == segments.Count);
      {
        return success;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: You have multiple conditional flow control statements (`if`, `for`, `while`). The compiler assumes the conditions _won't_ be met, so you need return statements _outside_ those statements. Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: You probably mean `while(success == false)` (or even `while(!success)`) and not `while(success = false)`. Also please remove `;` from `if(counter == segments.Count);`

Comment: one advice, please write small methods and avoid nested if.

Comment: Does this `List segments, List nodes` even compile? I would expect `List<Something>` (lists of *something*)

Comment: Thank you Rafalon for your input! Best wishes, Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have several issues here:

1) as Rafalon wrote in his comment, you should use the == operator in your while loop

2) As you have a for loop within your while loop and as you are returning on success, you do not need the while at all.

3) Also your else path is useless, as counter can only be smaller or equal to i, you will never meet the case counter == segments.Count, as the for loop will end before.

Just return true on success and false in any other case at the very end of the method.
Your code should look somewhat like this:

```
bool ComputePaths(ref Curve sprout, List segments, List nodes)
{
    double threshold = 0.5;

    for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
    {
        Vector3d a = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtStart;
        Vector3d b = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtEnd;

        if (a.Length < threshold | b.Length < threshold)
        {
            Point3d origin = new Point3d();
            origin = sprout.PointAtStart;
            List<Curve> segmentsToJoin = new List<Curve>();
            segmentsToJoin.Add(sprout);
            segmentsToJoin.Add(segments[i]);
            Curve[] segmentsJoined = new Curve[1];
            segmentsJoined = Curve.JoinCurves(segmentsToJoin, threshold);
            sprout = segmentsJoined[0];
            Vector3d c = sprout.PointAtStart - origin;

            if (c.Length > threshold)
            {
                sprout.Reverse();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < nodes.Count; j++)
            {
                Vector3d d = sprout.PointAtEnd - nodes[j];

                if (d.Length < threshold)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

UPDATE: I just realised, that you are changing the parameter sprout in your for loop, so you have a different condition if you enter the for loop again a second time. so my points 2 and 3 are wrong.

```
bool ComputePaths(ref Curve sprout, List segments, List nodes)
{
    double threshold = 0.5;
    int counter = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3d a = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtStart;
            Vector3d b = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtEnd;

            if (a.Length < threshold | b.Length < threshold)
            {
                Point3d origin = new Point3d();
                origin = sprout.PointAtStart;
                List<Curve> segmentsToJoin = new List<Curve>();
                segmentsToJoin.Add(sprout);
                segmentsToJoin.Add(segments[i]);
                Curve[] segmentsJoined = new Curve[1];
                segmentsJoined = Curve.JoinCurves(segmentsToJoin, threshold);
                sprout = segmentsJoined[0];
                Vector3d c = sprout.PointAtStart - origin;

                if (c.Length > threshold)
                {
                    sprout.Reverse();
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < nodes.Count; j++)
                {
                    Vector3d d = sprout.PointAtEnd - nodes[j];

                    if (d.Length < threshold)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                counter += 1;
                if(counter == segments.Count);
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }    

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no `break` anywhere, so the last `return false;` is dead code.

Comment: Thank you Thomas! You helped a lot! Have a nice day, oliver.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your great help!
It´s working now.

Best wishes, 
Oliver

SOLVED:

```
 bool ComputePaths(ref NurbsCurve sprout, List<Curve> segments, List<Vector3d> nodes)
  {
    double threshold = 0.5;
    int counter = 0;
    while(true)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
      {
        Vector3d a = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtStart;
        Vector3d b = sprout.PointAtEnd - segments[i].PointAtEnd;
        if (a.Length < threshold | b.Length < threshold)
        {
          Point3d origin = new Point3d();
          origin = sprout.PointAtStart;

          List<Curve> segmentsToJoin = new List<Curve>();
          segmentsToJoin.Add(sprout);
          segmentsToJoin.Add(segments[i]);
          Curve[] segmentsJoined = new Curve[1];
          segmentsJoined = Curve.JoinCurves(segmentsToJoin, threshold);
          sprout = segmentsJoined[0].ToNurbsCurve();

          Vector3d c = sprout.PointAtStart - origin;
          if (c.Length > threshold)
          {
            sprout.Reverse();
          }

          for (int j = 0; j < nodes.Count; j++)
          {
            Vector3d d = sprout.PointAtEnd - new Point3d(nodes[j].X, nodes[j].Y, nodes[j].Z);
            if (d.Length < threshold)
            {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
        else
        {
          counter += 1;
          if(counter == segments.Count)
          {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```